# CIFilter causes a crash on iPhone 11 and XR

Tags: ios, swift, crash, core-image, cifilter

All init of CIFilter causes a crash for some devices iPhone 11 & iPhone XR. iOS version 13.3.1, 13.4.1.

I tried to import :

```
import CoreImage
import CoreImage.CIFilter
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins
```

But Its not working !
I use xCode 11.4.1 & xCode 11.5

I have tried several things:

```
        if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") {

        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5, y: 5)

        if let output = filter.outputImage?.transformed(by: transform) {
            return UIImage(ciImage: output)
        }
    }
```

or this :

```
let filter = CIFilter.qrCodeGenerator()
```

I also tried to link to `CoreImage.framework` explicitly in the target settings.

Crash log:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CocoaDebug                     0x1023a0adc perform_rebinding_with_section + 332
1  CocoaDebug                     0x1023a087c rebind_symbols_for_image + 416
2  libdyld.dylib                  0x1999c3f4c invocation function for block in dyld3::AllImages::runImageCallbacks(dyld3::Array<dyld3::LoadedImage> const&) + 244
3  libdyld.dylib                  0x1999c3768 dyld3::AllImages::runImageCallbacks(dyld3::Array<dyld3::LoadedImage> const&) + 160
4  libdyld.dylib                  0x1999c8dd8 dyld3::AllImages::loadImage(Diagnostics&, unsigned int, dyld3::closure::DlopenClosure const*, bool, bool, bool, bool) + 580
5  libdyld.dylib                  0x1999c89ec dyld3::AllImages::dlopen(Diagnostics&, char const*, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, void const*) + 868
6  libdyld.dylib                  0x1999ca434 dyld3::dlopen_internal(char const*, int, void*) + 364
7  libdyld.dylib                  0x1999bd6c0 dlopen + 116
8  CoreFoundation                 0x199bcf5c8 _CFBundleDlfcnLoadBundle + 156
9  CoreFoundation                 0x199af1eac _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 372
10 Foundation                     0x199ec27a8 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 316
11 CoreImage                      0x19b479bcc invocation function for block in register_more_builtins(void (NSString*) block_pointer) + 804
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x19986833c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x199869a68 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
14 CoreImage                      0x19b476318 register_more_builtins(void (NSString*) block_pointer) + 304
15 CoreImage                      0x19b476b40 classNameIsSystemFilter(NSString*) + 112
16 CoreImage                      0x19b476dbc +[CIFilter(CIFilterRegistryPrivate) filterWithName:setDefaults:] + 396
17 MYApp                          0x100656598 QRCodeViewController.generateQRCode(from:) + 4370490776 (<compiler-generated>:4370490776)
18 MYApp                          0x1006563a4 QRCodeViewController.viewDidLoad() + 28 (QRCodeViewController.swift:28)
19 MYApp                          0x10065642c @objc QRCodeViewController.viewDidLoad() + 4370490412 (<compiler-generated>:4370490412)
20 UIKitCore                      0x19d6a236c -[UIViewController _sendViewDidLoadWithAppearanceProxyObjectTaggingEnabled] + 104
21 UIKitCore                      0x19d6a6f20 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 952
22 UIKitCore                      0x19d6a730c -[UIViewController view] + 32
23 UIKitCore                      0x19d602fa4 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1148
24 UIKitCore                      0x19d617478 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 692
25 UIKitCore                      0x19d618818 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 176
26 UIKitCore                      0x19d5fb4fc -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 228
27 UIKitCore                      0x19e1de6a0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2168
28 QuartzCore                     0x1a08314a0 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 292
29 QuartzCore                     0x1a08318e0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 472
30 QuartzCore                     0x1a0843dc4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 144
31 QuartzCore                     0x1a0788884 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 304
32 QuartzCore                     0x1a07b33d0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 656
33 QuartzCore                     0x1a07b3fc8 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 96
34 CoreFoundation                 0x199b42c54 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36
35 CoreFoundation                 0x199b3d8e4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 420
36 CoreFoundation                 0x199b3dd84 __CFRunLoopRun + 1020
37 CoreFoundation                 0x199b3d660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
38 GraphicsServices               0x1a3f4e604 GSEventRunModal + 164
39 UIKitCore                      0x19dd1215c UIApplicationMain + 1944
40 MYApp                          0x100518e54 main + 4369190484 (<compiler-generated>:4369190484)
41 libdyld.dylib                  0x1999b91ec start + 4
```

With the simulator it works well.

Someone would have any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please show how you initialize the filter?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel My post is updated with more details...

Comment: This is indeed odd, though I saw this with another filter before. Have you tried linking to `CoreImage.framework` explicitly (in your target settings)?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Yes I tried, it still crashes.

Comment: Still a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61573397/cifilter-with-ciqrcodegenerator-cause-crash. Why do you not edit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61573397/cifilter-with-ciqrcodegenerator-cause-crash instead? You’ve asked this same question three times now!

Comment: @matt The system propose to me to write new question after your proposal to close it.
Sorry I'm not stackoverflow master... I just need to fix this bug!
Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: The way to get better help is to ask your question better. You have not even shown the complete crash log yet. You are using some third-party tool (CocoaDebug) that is getting in the way here. It would really help if you would get rid of it and show us a complete normal crash log.

Comment: If you're looking for an alternative, you might want to explore DebugSwift at https://github.com/DebugSwift/DebugSwift. It can be a helpful resource for your debugging needs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it.
The problem was the third-party `CocoaDebug` !
I remove the pod and I have no more crashes!
Thanks!

Comment: You can try https://github.com/DebugSwift/DebugSwift as an alternative :)